# Show that $\frac{|\sin x|}{x}$ is uniformly continuous on (0,1) and (-1,0) but not the union of both intervals

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Show that the function  $\frac{|\sin x|}{x}$  is uniformly continuous on each of the
intervals $I_1$ = (−1,0) and $I_2$ = (0,1). However show that this function f is not uniformly continuous on $I_1 ∪ I_2$.

Comment: To show that it is uniformly continuous in each of those intervals, show that the lateral limits exist at the end-points. Therefore the function can be extended to a continuous function on $[-1,0]$ and (separatedly with a different extension) on $[0,1]$. Now, by Cantor's theorem (continuous on a compact is uniformly continuous) the extensions are uniformly continuous. We finish by noticing that removing the end-points in their domain doesn't affect uniform continuity.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

[image: uniform continuity with as discontinuity]

Comment: i know how to prove that it is not uniform continuous at x = 0 by showing that limit at x = 0 doest exist but i dunno how to prove that it is uniform continuous on the two intervals

Comment: @user2675516 Hint for that: the restriction of a uniformly continuous function to a subset of its domain is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Showing it is continuous (product of two continuous functions) and has a bounded derivative should be more than enough